# How to use percentile and rank to give avg days for 90 percent of orders

Tags: sql, oracle11g, rank, percentile

I have table called `order` and it has 3 columns I'm interested in: `order ID`, `day order placed`, `day fulfilled`. `order ID` is unique.

I need to find out in how many days (on average) 90% of the orders placed in January of 2016 took to be paid.

If order 1 was fulfilled in 1 day, order 2 in 2 days, order 3 in 3 days... order 10 in 10 days, then I would need to calculate as such:

- number of orders = 10
- 90% of 10 = 9
- the first 9 of those 10 orders that were fulfilled, when arranged in ascending order, took: `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45` days to fulfill
- hence, avg day for first 90% of orders fulfilled is: `45/9 = 5` days.

How can I write a query to first arrange orders by "number of days to fulfill" and then calculate avg days it took for the first 90% of orders for that period?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, we would have to assume that most of the orders have been filled from January.

Second, you can do this with analytic functions.  Although the percentile functions work, I usually do this the old fashioned way . . . by using `row_number()` and `count(*)`:

```
select min(days)
from (select (coalesce(datefulfilled, trunc(sysdate)) - dateordered) as days,
             sum(count(*) over (order by  (coalesce(datefulfilled, trunc(sysdate)) - dateordered)) as cumecnt,
             sum(count(*)) over () as totalcnt
      from orders o
      group by  (coalesce(datefulfilled, trunc(sysdate)) - dateordered)
     ) d
where cumecnt >= 0.9 * cnt ;
```